# Is there a word "lazies"?

Tags: grammaticality

I see many usages of this word in google (http://www.google.com/search?q=lazies), but I can't find its definition.  What does it mean?  Is it proper to use it in the following sentence:

> This book is for lazies. (It's easy reading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Lazies* serves here as a noun for "lazy people".

Your example "this book is for lazies" probably means:

> This book is for lazy readers.

or, more implicitly:

> This book is easier  (or shorter) than books that lazy people would
>   normally avoid reading.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure I'd call it slang so much as just a standard usage of a substantive adjective.  Like *The good, the bad, and the ugly*.

Comment: @Dusty, good point - I'm editing the answer to remove the word slang.

Comment: I'd write a reply, but I've got a case of the lazies right now.